# Calendar times of equinoxes

Tags: earth, precession

I know that the dates and times of equinoxes are not the same every year, due to precession of the axis and perhaps other effects such as the year not containing an exact number of days.  The precession effect, of course, is periodic.  My question is, "What are the maximum dates and times for the vernal and autumnal equinoxes?"

Comment: The link below explains some of what you want, but the question really only makes sense over a specific time frame.  Over many thousands of years, the accuracy of the calendar falls out of sync and there won't me a max or min. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/March_equinox#:~:text=On%20the%20Gregorian%20calendar%2C%20the,earlier%20than%20the%20previous%20year.